# Can I make a field un-editable after time?

Tags: security, validation

Does anybody know of a way to make a field un-editable after 24 or maybe 48 hours of the creation of a record ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about a validation rule checking off of created date?

Updated:
This should do it-

```
ISCHANGED(field) && TODAY()-DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) > 2
```

Comment: Would you just set the validation rule to check for a change in the value of the field and automatically set it back ?

Comment: Well, check if there is a change on the field, if there is then throw an error message saying it cannot be changed.

Comment: Make sure that you have exceptions for your admins, data cleaners, etc. I.e. AND(ISCHANGED(Field), Today()-DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) > 2, $ProfileID != AdminID, DatapeepsID)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, here's how to do it

Create a time dependant wrokflow rule. 2 days after the record was created, have it change a new field Lock_field__c to be true. for your validation rule, if lock_field__c == true; you can not edit it

Comment: maybe a validation rule which did this :

TODAY() - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) > 2;
AND ISCHANGED( Field__c );
Error{"You are not allowed to change that field after 2 days"}

Does that seem right ?

Comment: Cool. Make sure you allow exceptions for your admin team and your ETL